# Append csv to excel

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

csv File that updates every day  at 1amto show what repairs have been done

I created a flow but it is too slow as I have a few files and the size can be quite large.

I would like to use a power query so when I click refresh all the csv rows are added below the table in excel.

currently with my power query it overwrites it.

I have tried looking on the interet and using 2 queries and the append feature but the closest I got was this that stiches 2 files together but does not write the lines below when i change them in the repairs.csv

I feel it should be easy but im missing something.... (as usual)

Hopefully someone knows the query and im just missing some simple add row to my table kind of code

my query is

```
let
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp\REPAIRS.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Row_Num", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"CPU_Type", type text}, {"Fault", type text}, {"Reapair", type text}, {"Engineer", type text}, {"Success", Int64.Type}}),

// Custom step to append new data to the existing data
PreviousStep = Table.Buffer(#"Changed Type"),
Source2 = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\temp\REPAIRS2.csv"), [Delimiter=",", Columns=7, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"NewData" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source2, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"AppendedData" = Table.Combine({PreviousStep, #"NewData"})
```

in
#"AppendedData"

the table is
this is changed from 1 2 3 etc

[image: repairs1]

this is the second table... maybe it should have been blank. doesn't seem to help

[image: TABLE2]

this is what I get out. I am looking for 9 rows at this point but it just changed rows 2 and 3
[image: Output]

Comment: I just re read it and realised repairs2.csv is supposed to be the new data. but adding rows to this just changes the second half of the rows and doesnt add new rows to the bottom of the table.

Comment: In general, PowerQuery does not preserve any data, it always overwrites. If you need to preserve something, you need to make a copy and store it elsewhere before the next refresh

Comment: thank you  for the reply horseyride.  maybe an intersting slant. could power query from the table to a list then back from a list to a table but then im back to my power flow 5000 limit etc and it got very complex and too many failure points.. 
a power query that adds seems like a pretty common need for anyone getting csv files.
you never know someone may have solved this with a natty trick :)

Comment: Hi. 
got it sorted your your idea of copy data...for anyone who finds this. I as usual I cheated.
I made a flow that checks the email subject on a switch and then puts the CSV file in a folder. and when i do this I use this to name the file " REPAIRS utcNow('dd-MM-yyyy').CSV  " is the file name so each time it will get a new name, then power query combine on folder for the csv files and tada all the files in the table  :)

Comment: An excellent solution

Answer (score 0):

to close the thread.

I made a flow that checks the email subject on a switch and then puts the CSV file in a folder. and when i do this I use this to name the file " REPAIRS utcNow('dd-MM-yyyy').CSV " is the file name so each time it will get a new name, then power query combine on folder for the csv files and tada all the files in the table :)

one thing to note when it combines the CSV it leaves the name in one line blank. Go into power query and right click the column that is blank and filter(the down arrow) and select Remove Empty. This will then get only the correct rows.